# Single selection recyclerView not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, listener, android-recyclerview

I'm using `singleSelection recyclerView` it was working correct in `activity` but when i conevert it `activity` to `fragment` it's showing me **error** like [image: this]

**I'm using this code in freagment**

```
public class HomeworkFragment extends Fragment implements HomeworkAdapter.SingleClickListener
```

.

```
adapter = new HomeworkAdapter(view.getContext(), productList);
                        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(view.getContext()); //error here
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

.

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClickListener(int position, View view) {
        adapter.selectedItem();
    }
```

**This code in Adapter**

```
private static SingleClickListener sClickListener;


 public void setOnItemClickListener(SingleClickListener clickListener) {
        sClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface SingleClickListener {
        void onItemClickListener(int position, View view);
    }
```

I don't know what is the problem but i tries only fewThings like `getActivity()`, `view.getContext()` but nothing works

When it was in activity I was doing this `adapter.setOnItemClickListener(HomeworkActivity.this);` it was working fine in activity

Thanks in advance!

Happy coding!

Comment: The method `setOnItemClickListener` expects a `SingleClickListener` object as parameter but you've provided a `Context`.

Comment: but in activity `this` was working correctly so i think it also needs `activity` name here which can be only provided by `getActivity()`;

Comment: If `this` was working correctly then it means that the activity was the SingleClickListener object. If this is the case and you are calling your fragment from that activity then cast it. `adapter.setOnItemClickListener((SingleItemClickListener) view.getContext())`.

Comment: It's giving me error like this `cannot be cast to com.ngfcet.ngfconnection.adapter.HomeworkAdapter$SingleClickListener`

Comment: you can replace `view.getContext()` with `this` as `this` refers now to the fragment not the activity

Comment: ... as long as the fragment *is a* `SingleItemClickListener`.

Comment: `this` forcing me to change `SingleClickListener` to `ValueEventListener`

Comment: It's maybe because I'm using `firebase` and `adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);` is inside `addValueEventListener`

Comment: Pasting the files of the code involved might help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

your method `setOnItemClickListener(SingleClickListener clickListener)` takes `SingleClickListener`  as an  argument so you should pass `this` or `HomeFragment.this` instead of `context`

Comment: but how can i pass `this` in fragment?

Comment: @Tusharverma here you are passing `this` as a reference for 'SingleClickListener '  not for context & you already implement `HomeworkAdapter.SingleClickListener`  in fragment

Comment: please explain me now what to do?

Comment: `this` forcing me to change `SingleClickListener` to `ValueEventListener`

Comment: It's maybe because I'm using `firebase` and `adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);` is inside `addValueEventListener`

Comment: use `HomeworkFragment.this` instead if its inside `addValueEventListener` otherwise make it anonymous method

Comment: I don't think `HomeFragment.this` can work in `fragment`

Comment: just try it, otherwise make it anonymous method